# Open Authorized File and Stream it to Output

Tags: php

I'm trying to use examples on stackoverflow but cannot find anything that will work in PHP.  I'm trying to stream a large file from a server but then in real time stream it to the output in PHP.  The thing is I cannot seem to accomplish it because the file needs authorization.  I have the credentials because it's my home server.  Has anyone accomplished this?

```
$ch = curl_init();
$writefunc = function($ch, $chunk) {
    print $chunk;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    return len($chunk);
};
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 8096);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION , $writefunc);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: You mean the server is going and getting the file, then streaming it to the client? cURL is often use (Guzzle might help). But your description isn't very clear.

Comment: Yes, I've tried with curl with the writefunction option but all I get is one chunk.  I was hoping someone had an example using an authorized file with any command or curl hopefully.  I'll post the example if that will help.

Comment: Try reducing the PHP cURL read buffer with the `CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE` option. Also verify (on Apache) that compression is turned off. Otherwise, your code looks OK to me.

Comment: Thanks figured it out, it turns out I had to remove the curl_init() from this example...was staring at it too long, thanks all for responding back!